# How to indicate that an iPhone app is compatible with 1st gen iPod Touch?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

My app appears as "Compatible with iPhone and iPod touch (2nd generation).", I would like to make it "compatible with all iPhone and iPod touches (any generation)", do you know how to do that?

I've read the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedFeatures/AdvancedFeatures.html) on this, but it's unclear how that is done. What is the magic setting that marks an app compatible with all iPhoneOS devices?

My app (http://esmiler.com/currencypad/) does work on all devices... but it looks like the default is 2nd generation iPod Touch and above... or I changed some setting by mistake at some point. Any help on this appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading your app to iTunes Connect, you have been asked what your app is compatible with (or at least I have been). It seems like you selected 'iPhone & iPod touch (2nd gen)'. I suggest you dive into iTunes Connect and check if you can change the compatibility settings (maybe look into the iTunes Connect manual).

/edit: seems like they changed it. You now have to change your app's Info.plist and therefore upload a new binary.

Comment: I'm about to upload a new binary. Looked everywhere on iTunes Connect, it seems to be specified in info.plist now. I'm just trying to figure out what to put in info.plist :)